# How to prevent TextChanged event when dialog is loading

Tags: vb.net, textchanged

I have a dialog in my Program with 2 textboxes; **Path** and **Prefix**. and the following event.

```
  Private Sub Path_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Path.TextChanged
        Prefix.Text = GetDefaultPrefix(Path.Text)
   End Sub
```

My Path has a default value which is set before showing the dialog.

I don't want **GetDefaultPrefix** to be called when the dialog is loading, but only afterwards when the Path value is being changed. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can either set a flag at the end of the form load event which you use to know whether to act on the change event use AddHandler to activate the event after the form has loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the old Boolean hack where you create a Boolean value set to True, in the Load event change the value to False, and in the TextChanged event only execute the code if the value is False:

```
Private is_startup As Boolean = True
Private Sub FormDialog_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    is_startup = False
End Sub

Private Sub Path_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Path.TextChanged
    If Not is_startup Then Prefix.Text = GetDefaultPrefix(Path.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Easy and useful way.